# Chrome not reading HTTP Status Codes

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I am setting the HTTP Status Code value server-side and trying to read this value from the calling jQuery Ajax method.  I am forcing a return Status Code of 401.  Chrome displays a HTTP Status Code of 0; while FF, IE and Safari show the expected HTTP Status Code of 401.

**jQuery Ajax Call:**

```
/* change password */
var reqEmail = "?Email=" + getURLParameter('email');
var reqToken = "&ResetToken=" + getURLParameter('token');
var reqPassword = '&Password=' + password;
var reqPath = '../ws/visitor/SetPassword' + reqEmail + reqPassword + reqToken;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: reqPath,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
  complete: function (xhr) {
    console.log("Status: " + xhr.status);
    console.log("StatusText: " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

**Response Captured in Fiddler:**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Tue, 22 Oct 2013 19:03:34 GMT
```

**Chrome Console Log:**

```
Status: 0
StatusText: error
```

**FireFox Console Log:**

```
Status: 401
StatusText: Unauthorized
```

**C# Setting HTTP Status Code:**

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

**Also:**

Chrome will display the Status Code for: 204, 205, 304, when I set HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode equal to that value.

Does anyone have any ideas why I'm having trouble reading the HTTP status code in Chrome?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `console.log(xhr)` and look through the available properties/methods.

Comment: The object confirms status:0, statusText: "error"

Comment: if you add a status code callback for 401, does it trigger in all browsers?

Comment: No it does not.  I switched to return a 200, just to see the behavior.  In the "Network" Profiler for Chrome, the main view says Status - "Failed" for that Ajax request.  But when I click into that entry to get the details for it.  The "Headers" says "Status Code:200 OK"

Comment: Does the network tab of chrome console show the same (request and response) headers as the network tab in, say, firefox? I'm trying to find some specific discrepancy that we can start to look for a solution to, as i haven't had any problems getting the correct status code from an ajax request in chrome like you are describing. usually a statuscode of 0 is due to same-origin policy.

Comment: Are you working from file://?

Comment: No I am not working from file, it's running from IIS.

Comment: Within the network Profiler for Chrome, it shows the Response data as being empty, says "This request has no response data available", but within Fiddler and the other browser, the Response does have a JSON body.

Comment: hmm... how does removing the dataType change things? i wonder if the reason jquery is giving you 0 is because the responseText is coming up blank (obviously, thats another problem entirely, but we'll get to that next).

Comment: I removed "dataType" and still the same thing.

Comment: Also I set the ajax call as "async: false", and the error message return of xhr is "NetworkError: A network error occurred."

Comment: This is not a Cross Site call either, the ajax is consuming a service located within its website.

Comment: It's starting to look like either a jquery bug or a chrome bug. i don't see any reason within your setup for it to be happening.

Comment: I appreciate the help Kevin.  I agree it just almost feels like maybe there's something picky about Chrome.